# Leaflet MarkerCluster LayerSupport: Markers do not appear during pan on mobile browsers

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

With Leaflet MarkerCluster LayerSupport extension, when moving the map from the mobile device, the markers disappear to go back only when the drag is released.

```js
var mcgLayerSupportGroup = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport();
```

You can try here:

https://jsfiddle.net/DanyIdas/k08rbwu5/36/
or
http://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on the README of the [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport#regular-mcg-options-events-and-methods) subplugin:

> Regular MCG options, events and methods
>
> All regular MCG [options](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#all-options), events and methods are available within MCG Layer Support. Refer to Leaflet.markercluster documentation.

In particular, you have the Leaflet.markercluster [`removeOutsideVisibleBounds` option](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#enabled-by-default-boolean-options):

> removeOutsideVisibleBounds: Clusters and markers too far from the viewport are removed from the map for performance.

Therefore you can just use (disable in your case) that option with the LayerSupport subplugin:

```js
const mcgLayerSupportGroup = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({
  removeOutsideVisibleBounds: false // Disable default behaviour
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdunypa2/

Note: you do not need to create a regular markerClusterGroup, just the layerSupport is enough, as shown in the subplugin [quick guide](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport#quick-guide).

Comment: Thank you so much for the support!